# TSQL LEAD WITH TIME INTERVALS

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, subquery

I am trying to improve performance for this query:

[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/f615c/6)

```
    SELECT Ts.[TripID]
      ,Ts.[RDate]
      ,Ts.[RTime]
      ,Ts.[Passengers]
      ,Ts.[Other]
      ,Ts.[RecordStatusID]
      ,IIF(Ts.RecordStatusID = 1, '', CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),
                             (SELECT        SUM((IIF(Passengers + Other < 8, 1, CEILING((Passengers + Other) / 7.0))))
                               FROM            dbo.tblTrips T
                               WHERE        ISNULL(T.ActualDateTime, CAST(T.RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(T.RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)) BETWEEN ISNULL(Ts.ActualDateTime, CAST(Ts.RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(Ts.RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)) AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 35, 
                                                         ISNULL(Ts.ActualDateTime, CAST(Ts.RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(Ts.RTime AS SMALLDATETIME))) AND T.RecordStatusID > 1)) + ' Trips') AS Trips
  FROM tblTrips Ts
  ORDER BY Ts.RDate, Ts.RTime
```

I am really not sure how to do this any other way, any help would be appreciated.

The objective here is to count 35 minute intervals for each row, showing how many trips from the current trip time (rdate + rtime) + 35 minutes, i tried doing grouping but the result isn't what i'm looking for. I'm wondering if there's a lead with time intervals that i could specify a condition and use a count on that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to split the operations. For example:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblTrips;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tblTripsAgg;


CREATE TABLE #tblTrips
(
     [TripID] [int] NOT NULL 
    ,[Record] INT 
    ,[ActualDateTime] [datetime] 
    ,PRIMARY KEY ([TripID])
);

CREATE TABLE #tblTripsAgg
(
     [TripID] [int] NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
    ,Trips INT
);

INSERT INTO #tblTrips ([TripID], [Record], [ActualDateTime])
SELECT TripID
      ,IIF(RecordStatusID = 1, 0, IIF(Passengers + Other < 8, 1, CEILING((Passengers + Other) / 7.0)))
      ,CAST(RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)
FROM tblTrips

INSERT INTO #tblTripsAgg
SELECT TS.[TripID]
        ,SUM(T.[Record])
FROM #tblTrips TS
LEFT JOIN #tblTrips T
    ON T.[ActualDateTime] >= TS.[ActualDateTime]
    AND T.[ActualDateTime] <= DATEADD(MINUTE, 35, TS.[ActualDateTime])
GROUP BY TS.[TripID]

SELECT A.[TripID]
      ,A.[RDate]
      ,A.[RTime]
      ,A.[Passengers]
      ,A.[Other]
      ,A.[RecordStatusID]
      ,IIF(A.RecordStatusID = 1, '', CONCAT(Trips, ' Trips')) AS Trips
FROM tblTrips A
INNER JOIN #tblTripsAgg DS
    ON A.TripID = ds.TripID;
```

Why? First because sometimes complex queries are not optimized correctly by the SQL engine and second - you can easily see which part of the process is the slowest.

For, example in the above example, the first part is just making  our date and time in one date. Also, we are calculating some additional stuff there. So, if this part of the query takes a lot of time just precalculated it - using a trigger, using a compute precalculated column or when the application is touching the table.

Then in the second query, we are calculating the sum for each `trip id`. If this part is slow, maybe we can create a different index on the table including the `ActualDateTime` or if always the current trip ID has date bigger then the previous, we can add `TS.TripID > T.TripID` in order to limit the rows further?

As you said in the comments, 300 000 rows are handled, but this is really small amount of data, so it it really should not take so many time to execute. If you can optimize the query further, share a data dump.

---

You can create a index view to precalculated automatically the results of the first query, so no additional efforts are needed.

```
DROP VIEW IF EXISTS  dbo.vw_tblTrips;
GO

CREATE VIEW dbo.vw_tblTrips WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS 
SELECT TripID AS [TripID]
      ,IIF(RecordStatusID = 1, 0, IIF(Passengers + Other < 8, 1, CEILING((Passengers + Other) / 7.0))) AS [Record]
      ,CAST(RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(RTime AS SMALLDATETIME) AS [ActualDateTime]
FROM dbo.tblTrips;

GO

CREATE UNIQUE CLUSTERED INDEX INX_vw_tblTrips   
    ON dbo.vw_tblTrips ([ActualDateTime], [TripID]);  
GO
```

Comment: Thank you for the insight. I performed the steps you outlined and found that the longest query with the heaviest cost was the second insert (insert into #tblTripsAgg) it was missing an index on ActualDateTime (This isn't the case with the original table in question in my database) so I created it ((USE [tempdb]
GO
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [<Name of Missing Index, sysname,>]
ON [dbo].[#tblCrew____________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000021] ([ActualDateTime])
INCLUDE ([Record])) After that the insert took one second

Comment: @user1848850 So, are you able to optimize your real query following the steps above? For 300, 000 rows I really believe your query should be executed for seconds.

Comment: The final select statement took 2 seconds for the 300,000 records. Which leaves me a bit confused as to how to approach this. The op is the exact statement in a view which the application uses. Normally the application will query that view with a where clause with a date range. The performance is still terrible even with a date range. To modify my solution to fit yours, i would require to calculate this using a trigger on tblTrips table and create an actual tblTripsAgg table ? The interesting part here is the fact that the index for ActualDateTime exists on tblTrips but the performance is bad

Comment: @user1848850 As I said, sometimes queries are a little bit complex and the engine is not able to build the best execution plan. Also, I have added to the question a way to create a index view for the first part of the query. It will precalculated the data from the first step automatically.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Your solution definitely works. The only question i have is whether or not i should precalculate everything during CRUD operations or maybe using a stored procedure to create a temporary table and then query them which avoids the correlated subquery

Comment: @user1848850 If you do the calculations in real time (using stored procedure, using trigger or indexed view) you can guarantee that your queries will always reflect the latest state of the data. What can be wrong is that if your code is not written well (for example loop in trigger) or your system is under heavy load, you can delay this `CRUD` operations. The second approach solve this but you must ensure the routine is always executed before reading the data. I am personally using both of the approach in my environment depending on the workload.

Comment: Oh I see, i completely forgot about creating indexes on views. All this time i've been just creating indexes on the main table. I will definitely need to play around with this and see what's the best approach. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction to solve this performance problem.

Comment: Yes, creating index on the view precalculated the data automatically. But check the docs because some views cannot be indexed (for example when in the query there is `LEFT JOIN`) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/views/create-indexed-views?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Would you lean towards modifying the application to include these calculations on the client side upon CRUD and creating an additional hidden field like [Record] or using Triggers and Stored Procedures on the backend ?

Comment: @user1848850 If you are able to modify the application to perform such calculations it will be great. I believe it is the better way. Unfortunately, because of legacy dependencies rewriting or changing the app is not always easy and you move the logic into the database. If you can change the app - go for it.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

On fiddler this is 9ms compared to your solution that is 11ms
The idea is to merge the time and date field one time and then use it.
for the other parts I did not exactly what you are doing.

```
  ;with cte as (
    select *,ISNULL(ActualDateTime, CAST(RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)) TripsTime
    ,isnull(nullif(CEILING((Passengers + Other)/7.0),0),1) ICPO FROM tblTrips 
  )
  select  [TripID],[RDate],[RTime],[Passengers],[Other],[RecordStatusID]
 , IIF(Ts.RecordStatusID = 1, '',
    (select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),SUM(ICPO))+ ' Trips' from cte T where 
        T.TripsTime between Ts.TripsTime and DATEADD(MINUTE, 35,Ts.TripsTime)
        AND T.RecordStatusID > 1))
     AS Trips
   from cte Ts ORDER BY Ts.RDate, Ts.RTime
```

Comment: The issue i'm having has to do with the correlated sub query, with a table of just 300,000 records i ran it for 2 hours and 46 minutes and it's still going. Taking a very long time!

Answer (score 1):

I guess you could avoid the correlate sub query by self joining the table:

```
SELECT
         Ts.[TripID]
       ,Ts.[RDate]
       ,Ts.[RTime]
       ,Ts.[Passengers]
       ,Ts.[Other]
       ,Ts.[RecordStatusID]
       , IIF(Ts.RecordStatusID = 1, '',
         cast(     
                       SUM(IIF(tl.Passengers + tl.Other < 8, 1, CEILING((tl.Passengers + tl.Other) / 7.0)))
        as varchar(10)
         ) + ' Trips') AS Trips
FROM
         tblTrips Ts
         inner join tblTrips Tl
         on 
          Tl.RecordStatusID > 1
          and (
         (ts.tripid=tl.tripid and Ts.RecordStatusID = 1) or
         (  Ts.RecordStatusID > 1 and
        ISNULL(Tl.ActualDateTime, CAST(Tl.RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(Tl.RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)) BETWEEN 
            ISNULL(Ts.ActualDateTime, CAST(Ts.RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(Ts.RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)) 
                AND DATEADD(MINUTE, 35, ISNULL(Ts.ActualDateTime, CAST(Ts.RDate AS SMALLDATETIME) + CAST(Ts.RTime AS SMALLDATETIME)))
            ))
GROUP BY
     Ts.[TripID]
       ,Ts.[RDate]
       ,Ts.[RTime]
       ,Ts.[Passengers]
       ,Ts.[Other]
       ,Ts.[RecordStatusID]             
ORDER BY
         Ts.RDate
       , Ts.RTime
```

Comment: I tried your approach but unfortunately it still takes the same amount of time to process 300,000 records. No performance increase. Query analyzer shows Nested Loops is 96% of the cost.